# How to connect Django to a MySQL database over an SSL connection?

Tags: mysql, django, ssl

I'm trying to connect Django to a MySQL database which is accessible through an SSL connection. How do I configure this?

My first guess would be setting the 'OPTIONS' property of the database definition. However, I can't find info on what possible options to use. The option `'ssl': '/map/to/ca-cert.pem'` does not work.

The following command seems to work:

```
mysql -h url.to.host -u lizard -p --ssl-ca=./ca-cert.pem
```

Edit: Ok I'm looking at the python-mysqldb documentation... maybe I can find the answer there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Django uses the Python `MySQLdb` library to interface with MySQL. Looking at [the MySQLdb connection documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#connection-objects), it looks like the `ssl` option requires a dictionary argument. So this might work:

```
'OPTIONS': {'ssl': {'key': '/map/to/ca-cert.pem'}}
```

Comment: Thanks. It also works with 'ca' instead of 'key'. The answer was on this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-ssl-set.html

Comment: It seems that 'ca' is the correct option, 'key' on its own caused MySQL to not verify the contents. Read more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287088/ca-ssl-parameter-for-python-mysqldb-not-working-but-key-does and here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62743

Answer (score 15):

The MySQL client must be provided with three keys:

- CA cert
- client cert
- client key

See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-ssl-certs.html) for the instructions for creating these keys and setting up the server.

NOTE: There is an [open issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64870) that seems to be related to using openssl v1.0.1 to create the certificates for mysql 5.5.x

This is an example entry for the Django settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': '<DATABASE NAME>',                     
        'USER': '<USER NAME>',
        'PASSWORD': '<PASSWORD>',
        'HOST': '<HOST>', 
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS':  {
            'ssl': {'ca': '<PATH TO CA CERT>',
            'cert': '<PATH TO CLIENT CERT>',
            'key': '<PATH TO CLIENT KEY>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the "must be" in the first sentence is correct unless cert+key **authentication** is being used (in contrast to just encrypting the network traffic).

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a "SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed')
"error when running `python manage.py migrate`

I used pip to install django-mysql-ssl package. It still wasn't working. I had to change "ca" to "ssl-ca" and now it works.

```
'OPTIONS':  {
                    'ssl': {'ssl-ca': '<PATH TO CA CERT>',

                            }
                      }
```

I'm not sure if it is actually using encryption, but it no longer throws an error. I am running local django app connected to an AWS mariaDB instance.

Edit: django-mysql-ssl package is not required starting from Django 1.8, as the functionality is built-in now. 
[See Dependencies section in the package description here](https://pypi.org/project/django-mysql-ssl/)

> ### Dependencies
>
> This application is confirmed to work with Django 1.5. It should also
>   work with Django 1.6-1.7. This plugin is not necessary for Django 1.8,
>   as the capability is built into the core.

Comment: I got the same error and `'ssl': {'ssl-ca': '<PATH TO CA CERT>'` worked for me too. Also, I see the path to the CA cert can be anything, even non-existent, and it still works fine. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543985/8645590.

Comment: _"I'm not sure if it is actually using encryption"_ @BBaker, the connection will be encrypted, I checked by doing `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of SSL encrypted connection will probably need `cipher` parameter

```
DATABASE = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'pass',
        'HOST': 'host',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'ssl': {
                'ca': 'path/to/pem',
                'key': 'path/to/pem',
                'cert': 'path/to/pem',
                'cipher': 'AES128-SHA' #| 'AES128-SHA256' | 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MySQL passes a default cipher list to the SSL library.
More details can be found here:

1. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html#encrypted-connection-cipher-configuration
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html#encrypted-connection-protocol-negotiation

Can't leave comments for @Drew answer, so let it be new one.