# Specify the --ssl option for django database connection

Tags: django, ssl

When I connect to my database with `mysql` I specify the option `--ssl`, or else I get the error

`SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.`

I know that with MySQL you can connect with a ssl certificate where you have a copy of the certificate locally. With this approach I know how to move forward with Django, as you can specify the option as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12285601/2889451

However, in my case I simply pass the option --ssl, and I don't have a local copy of the certificate. 
**How can I enable this option in Django?**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can solve it by passing the options as shown below:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': DB_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {'ssl': True},
    }
}
```

Comment: there is also `'OPTIONS': {'sslmode': 'require'}` for postgres backend ref https://stackoverflow.com/q/47683059

Comment: It is trying to get `ca` attribute of `ssl` but it does not exist on bool value. So this one cause an error.

see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/cafe7266ee69f7e017ddbc0d440084ace559b04b/django/db/backends/mysql/client.py#L24C13-L24C13